# Qt- 'createD Tables' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

I'm going to drop record from database and create it again. I have two source class, **Main.cpp & MainWindows.cpp**. 
in **Main.cpp**, I've define a function, called *createDBTables()*

```
bool createDBTables()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("DROP TABLE contacts");
    return query.exec("CREATE TABLE contacts ("
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                "name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, "
                "status VARCHAR(1024), "
                "profpic VARCHAR(256), "
                "register_state INTEGER NOT NULL, "
}
```

I declare this function in **Main.cpp** because I want to use it in this source file also I want use this function in another source file- **MainWindow.cpp**-

 I tried to use this:

```
void MainWindows::showAccountDeactivation()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox(this);
    QFont font = msgBox.font();
    msgBox.setWindowTitle(CGlobalZone::m_softwareName);
    msgBox.setInformativeText(tr("Are you sure you want to remove your account?"));
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok| QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Ok , tr("Ok"));
    msgBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Cancel , tr("Cancel"));
    int ret = msgBox.exec();
    switch (ret)
    {
       case QMessageBox::Ok:
        {
             createDBTables();
        }
            break;
        case QMessageBox::Cancel:
            QTimer::singleShot(1500, this, SLOT(close()));
            break;
    }
}
```

But it shows to me this:
 *'createD Tables' was not declared in this scope* 
I've added this line:
 `bool  createDBTables();` instead of  `createDBTables();` but , it warned me about *Unused variable*, How to use this function in the right way? when I declared createDBTables() in MainWindows.cpp , it warned me about duplicate definition of function.

Comment: Why don't you define `createDBTables()` function in your `MainWindow.cpp`? That would solve the problem.

Comment: You should really think about where to put your functions. Does it makes sense to define it in _main.cpp_? Could it be more suitable to create something like _sql_utils.h_ where you declare the function and _sql.utils.cpp_ where you define it? Just one possibility but probably more suitable

Comment: @vahancho when I declared createDBTables() in MainWindows.cpp , it warned me about duplicate definition of function.

Comment: @afn, what prevents you from finding and removing the duplication?

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer:**

You should create `Main.h` file, containing:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#defing MAIN_H

bool createDBTables();

#endif // MAIN_H
```

and include it in the beginning of your `Main.cpp` and `MainWindow.cpp` files:

```
#include "Main.h"
...
```

**Explanation:**

Each entity in C++ must have a definition and can have up to several declarations. What you wrote in `Main.cpp` file is a definition. A declaration is used to give a compiler know, that this entity is defined somewhere below in this unit, or in other unit (like in your case). Without a declaration a compiler does not know that your function even exist. And that is exactly, what is written in your error string.

If you want to know more, you should read info about how a compiler and linker work.

p.s.: I would also agree with **Bowdzone**. You should not write utility functions in main.cpp. Utility functions belong to utility units.